# Opencv's image.empty() function not working

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video-capture

The below code works fine until the USB camera is removed while the program is running. After disconnecting the USB camera I see a blank image, but the program should stop because `img_cam1.empty()` and `!cap_cam1.isOpened()` should be true. However for some reason both are false!

What is causing this?

```
VideoCapture cap_cam1(0);
Mat img_cam1;

while(true)
{

    cap_cam1 >> img_cam1;

    if (img_cam1.empty() || !cap_cam1.isOpened())
    {                               
        cap_cam1.release();  
         break;                 
    }

    else {        
        imshow("Live",img_cam1); 
        if (!img_cam1.isContinuous())
           break;
        img_cam1.empty();               
        img_cam1.release();

        if(waitKey(33)==27) break; 
    }
}
```

How to stop the program when the USB camera is removed?

Comment: Seems like a bug. Have you tried the combination of [`grab`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ae38c2a053d39d6b20c9c649e08ff0146) and [`retrieve`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a9ac7f4b1cdfe624663478568486e6712) instead of `>>` operator?

Comment: Does it continue indefinitely? Or is there a number of loops executed before it stops? i.e. it hasn't updated yet

Comment: Also please format your code clearly and in a similar style throughout this will improve its **readability** and hence make it easier for you to debug

Comment: @sgarizvi, i tried grab & retrieve,  read() , i see no difference. infact the imshow window becomes laggy when cam is removed.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, It continues forever ! i waited for long time

Comment: @PrakashM From the docs on `isOpened`: If the **previous call** to VideoCapture constructor or VideoCapture::open succeeded, the method returns true. So you might need to change the method to call `open` before you check `isOpened`. Let me know if this fixes the second issue

Answer (score 1):

From the [Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-isopened) (emphasis mine):

> If the **previous** call to VideoCapture constructor or VideoCapture::open succeeded, the method returns true.

It seems like you need to call [open](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-open) before you check whether or not `cap_cam1` is opened. So something like below:

```
cap_cam1.open(1);
if (img_cam1.empty() || !cap_cam1.isOpened())
```

Although I do not know the exact syntax myself to be able to show the exact code needed to solve the problem.

Regarding the issue with `img_cam1.empty()` I am of no help, however the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-empty) on `empty()` quotes:

> The method returns true if Mat::total() is 0 or if Mat::data is NULL. Because of pop_back() and resize() methods M.total() == 0 does not imply that M.data == NULL.

So maybe an data is still inside of `img_cam1` although I wouldn't know without debugging.

Comment: it looks like a bug in Opencv itself! 
cannot use cap_cam1.open(1);
as it keeps reopening camera within the while loop.. so image will be flickering

Comment: @PrakashM I understand but I do not know enough about OpenCV to be able to think of another "workaround"

Comment: @PrakashM Also have you checked that `img_cam1` has NULL data inside of it when the camera is unplugged?

Comment: no prob, thanks for your reply. 


img_cam1 is not null , as img_cam1.empty() is not true